# Angular 8 - reactive form directive e disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-8

Depois que eu atualizei do Angular 7 para o Angular 8 em uma aplicação o [disabled] deixou de funcionar em várias partes do template. E para carregar a aplicação eu precisei alterar para [attr.disabled]. Ainda não entendi muito bem o porque do 'attr.'

Mas de todo jeito o disabled em uma das partes do site deixou de funcionar como antes. A idéia era que o usuário pudesse selecionar até 5 tags dentro de uma selação com várias tags. Se ele selecionasse 5 tags ficava desabilitado. Se ele tirasse a seleção deixando 4 ou menos voltava a habilitar. E no angular 8 deixou de funcionar e agora aparece o erro abaixo

```
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

Example: 
form = new FormGroup({
  first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
  last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      });
```

**HTML**

```html
...
<div class="form-group col-5 col-md-3" *ngFor="let tag of tags" [attr.disabled]="desabilitar(tag)">
...
```

**Typescript**

```js
...
    public desabilitar(tag: Tag): boolean {
        return !this.exists(tag) && this.tagsEmpresa.length === 5;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro é mostrado em development mode, para avisar sobre a inconsistência no funcionamento do app.

Vocé deve ter iniciado o form group sem setar o disabled, ou seja `false`, e no mesmo `lifecycle hook` foi mudado para `true`, o que gerou este erro.. Isto é um alerta porque nem o angular nem você mesmo pode saber lidar com o estado do app caso tenha sido alterado o valor em runtime.

Só em `development mode` é detectado, porque o componente é renderizado 2 vezes para checar se os dados foram renderizados de forma consistente.

O modo que o `attr` resolve isso é sobrepondo o valor que seria setado dinamicamente pelo form builder, mas não a propriedade do DOM elemento que havia de ser renderizado no lifecycle.

Você pode ler mais sobre o Development mode e o que acontece no lifecycle de renderização neste [link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-what-is-unidirectional-data-flow-development-mode/)